# Bochs: display library 'sdl' not available

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, sdl, emulation, bochs

Recently I've started reading this "book" about OS development (https://littleosbook.github.io/), and I find it great and all that, but I came across a problem while trying to boot up my image in bochs.

At some point the guide about running the operating system in **Bochs** tells me to create a config file for the emulator. I set every option to what I read.

But when I run the following command,

`bochs -f bochsrc.txt -q`

it says:

> display library 'sdl' not available

The relevant line in the config file is pretty obvious:

> display_library: sdl

I don't know what's the problem. I installed both libsdl and libsdl2.0, but it still won't work.

My work environment consists of an Ubuntu 20.04 and a Bochs 2.6.11.

Has anybody faced with this issue? What's the solution?

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? I'm currently having the same issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42453950/9735208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a working fix. I changed the display_library to `sdl2` instead of `sdl` and  bosch ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when running my code on a Vagrant that had no windows manager installed.  I think that a windows manager has to be set up in order for bochs to be able to access the relevant libraries or whatever (don't quote me on that lol).  After I reinstalled the following dependencies over this Vagrantfile, I managed to get it to work.  It worked even better with bochs-x and x.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # Ubuntu 15.10
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
  end

  # Install xfce and virtualbox additions
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get update"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get install -y xfce4 virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11"
  # Permit anyone to start the GUI
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo sed -i 's/allowed_users=.*$/allowed_users=anybody/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config"
  # Install OS development requirements
end
```